# How to propagate a click from an invisible div to an embeded flash?

Tags: javascript, mouseclick-event

i need to propagate a click from an invisible div to an embeded flash (the two are superposed).

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="800" height="600">
            <param name="src" value="pub.swf">
            <param name="quality" value="high">
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
            <embed src="flash.swf" bgcolor="#CC0000" wmode="opaque"quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="225" height="150"></embed>
        </object>
        <div id="div"></div>
```

My objects are both well positioned, but I really don't succeed in transmitting the click from the top div to the embeded flash.

Any idea ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin events are separate from HTML. You can't catch an HTML click event from Flash and you can't catch a Flash click event from HTML.

You would have to alter the code of the `flash.swf` to provide an external method that simulated a click in the flash movie. eg. using [dispatchEvent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_07.html). You could then call this method from JavaScript in the HTML document when the invisible div was clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is there another method if you don't have access to the flash source code (my case)

Comment: Sorry, no. (Some people might see this as a deliberate feature, eg. advertisers don't want you messing with their ads.)